# Seaborn with multiple Columns

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have a dataframe data_gender:

| gender | math_score | reading_score | writing_score | avg_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| female | 63.63 | 72.61 | 72.47 | 69.57 |
| male | 68.73 | 65.47 | 63.31 | 65.84 |

and I want to make a seaborn barplot that looks like this plot that I made with matplotlib with simple line

```
data_gender.plot.bar(figsize=(8,6))
```

[image: matplotlib bar plot]

How would one do it with seaborn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and pass the data to [`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```
sns.barplot(data=data_gender.melt(id_vars='gender',
                                  value_name='score', var_name='course'),
            x='gender', y='score', hue='course')
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

sns.barplot(x='gender', y='score', hue='course', data=data_gender)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).